# Printing row of stars

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that takes two parameters: number of stars, and row length. I want the method to print stars from the middle of the row, and then expand outwards.

Number of stars has to be less than or equal to row length, and row length has to be odd numbers.

Say if I call

```
rowofStars(3,5);
```

Output I want is:

```
" *** "
```

But if I call

```
rowofStars(2,5);
rowofStars(4,5);
```

Output should be:

```
" * * "
"** **"
```

Quotation marks just to show the length of the row (in this case 5 char spaces).

All I can figure out is this involves a for loop, with length being the limit of the loop, and if number of stars == odd number, then

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

    //Set of rules should be here

    if(num % 2 == 1 && i == length % 2 + 1){
        System.out.print("*");
    } else {
        SYstem.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out the rest of the rules so that the stars are printed the way I want them to.

Comment: What would `rowOfStars(3,6)` output?

Comment: What about `rowOfStars(6,5)`? Would that be legal?

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. Can't believe I left some rules out, will edit shortly. num has to be smaller or equal to length, and length has to be an odd number (so that it always has a middle char space).

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. Create a character array with the given length:
char[] charArray = new char[length];

// 2. Fill this entire array with spaces initially:
java.util.Arrays.fill(charArray, ' ');

// 3. Fill the middle of the array with the appropriate amount of '*'
// num amount of times for odd, and num+1 amount of times for even
java.util.Arrays.fill(charArray, length/2 - num/2, length/2 + num/2 + 1, '*');

// 4. If the num was even, change the center spot back to a space:
if(num%2 == 0)
  charArray[length/2] = ' ';

// 5. Convert the character-array to a String
String result = new String(charArray);

// 6. And output the String:
System.out.println(result);
```

Example input: `num=4; length=7`

- After step 1 and 2: We now have a character array with 7 spaces: `[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']`.
- After step 3: We have now filled the middle of the array with 5 '*': `[' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ']` *†*
- After step 4: Now the center is back to a space because the `num` of 4 was even: `[' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ']`
- After step 5 and 6: The character-array has been converted to a String (`" ** ** "`) and printed to STDOUT.

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/OtOW6o)

*†: Here an explanation for the calculation parts:*

Let's say we keep the length 7 in this example, but have the num vary from 0 to 7. We will get the following calculations. Since we are working with integers, the `/2` will integer-divide, which implicitly truncates decimal values:

```
inputs     calculations                              indices

0,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(0/2=0), (7/2=3)+(0/2=0)+1   ->   3,4
1,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(1/2=0), (7/2=3)+(1/2=0)+1   ->   3,4
2,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(2/2=1), (7/2=3)+(2/2=1)+1   ->   2,5
3,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(3/2=1), (7/2=3)+(3/2=1)+1   ->   2,5
4,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(4/2=2), (7/2=3)+(4/2=2)+1   ->   1,6
5,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(5/2=2), (7/2=3)+(5/2=2)+1   ->   1,6
6,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(6/2=3), (7/2=3)+(6/2=3)+1   ->   0,7
7,7   ->   (7/2=3)-(7/2=3), (7/2=3)+(7/2=3)+1   ->   0,7
```

This resulting list are from and to indices we need for the '*' characters in our `Arrays.fill` method, which are in the [interval-notation `[a,b)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by steps

- put the correct number of space
- put the correct number of star
- save its reverse equivalent for the end
- put the middle element
- put the end

```
static String rowofStars(int nbStars, int size){
    if(nbStars>size) throw new IllegalArgumentException("nbStars>size");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int nbStarsOneSide = nbStars/2;
    int nbOneSide = size/2;

    for(int i=0; i<(nbOneSide-nbStarsOneSide); i++){
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<nbStarsOneSide; i++){
        sb.append("*");
    }

    String secondSide = new StringBuilder(sb.toString()).reverse().toString();
    sb.append(nbStars%2 != 0 ? "*" : " ");
    sb.append(secondSide);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

https://ideone.com/tOTQ0T